# Is it possible in Laravel to store a property in one route and use in another? (same class - different methods for different routes)

Tags: php, laravel-5

```
class MyController extends Controller {
    private $data;

    index() {

        $data = (object)[];

        $this->data = $data;

        return compact();
    }

    otherRouteMethod() {
        dd($this->data);
    }
}
```

**ROUTES**

```
Route::get('/my', MyController::class . '@index')->name('my.overview');
Route::get('/my/sub_route', MyController::class . '@otherRouteMethod');
```

Why is the following happening?

- Both routes work
- `dd($this->data)` prints "null" as it was not set in index()
- using `public` modifier for $data leads to the same issue

Is it because Laravel makes a new instance of the class on every route change?

Comment: Yes it is what you think. You will have to use cookies or sessions

Comment: Also you have to set the data propery with `$this->data`. But it won't be saved across requests anyway.

Comment: thanks @jrswgtr . Yes, the 2nd comment ... I just forgot (typo). For the rest is clear. Thank you

Comment: To save some typing, you don't need to use `MyController::class.'@function'` in Routes; it's ok to use `'MyController@function'` for example :P

Comment: well you could serialize the object, store it in a sessions variable and than unserialize it

Comment: @RobertRocha isnt the session variable meant for http session data (such as html headers to print in the template as part of HTML output)?

Comment: yeah, but it's a way to solve the problem across requests. Another way is creating a `static $variable` and storing data there

Comment: `private static $data` `MyController::$data = 'foo'